# Using self.objectname causes profiler to report a memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

Please help;

Header File

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface MyClass : NSObject {

    NSMutableString * myString;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString * myString;

-(id) init;
-(void) dealloc;

@end
```

Implementation File

```
#import "MyClass.h"


@implementation MyClass

@synthesize myString;

-(id) init {

    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [self.myString release];
}

@end
```

Usage

```
MyClass * m = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[m release];
//-- Xcode 4 profiler reports a memory leak here.
```

However, when the code in implementation file of the class is changed to not use the [self.myString .....] notation, then no memory leak is reported.

So,

```
    -(id) init {

           if ((self = [super init])) {
                myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            }

            return self;
        }
}
```

and

```
 -(void) dealloc {
        [super dealloc];
        [myString release];
    }
```

works fine. No memory leaks reported.

Any ideas - is it profiler or is it me (be nice)?

Comment: Don't call [super dealloc] first, it will free your instances memory and thus when you access an ivar later, you access already freed memory. Oh and about your questions, its you :)

Comment: And do `[myString release]`, not `[self.myString release]`. Otherwise, if you change the memory management semantic of the `myString` property to `copy` (which is technically what it should be) at some point, you'll end up leaking the string.

Comment: @jlehr - No he wouldn't. `Copy` only creates a copy when the property is *set*, not when it's *read*, meaning `[self.myString release]` would work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your memory leak is not *caused* by using your setter. Your memory leak is caused by you not managing your memory correctly!

If you declare the following property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id value;
```

That means that the compiler generates methods that look something like this (highly simplified):

```
- (id)value {
  return value;
}

- (void)setValue:(id)aValue {
  [value autorelease];
  value = [aValue retain];
}
```

When you use dot-notation, `self.value = obj` is desugared into `[self setValue:obj]`. Thence, you are actually causing `obj` to be retained within the setter. If you initially create an owning reference to `obj` (by using an `+alloc` without a corresponding `-release` or `-autorelease`), you'll have over-retained `obj`, and it will never be deallocated. Hence, you need to do something like this:

```
id obj = [[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease];
self.value = obj;
```

or

```
id obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
self.value = [obj autorelease];
```

or

```
id obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
self.value = obj;
[obj release];
```

Whatever you do, you need to make sure that when you assert ownership of an object (by retaining it), you also release it.

Comment: Thanks for visually providing alternate solutions. It helps me understand what I'm doing wrong and gives me some direction.

Answer (score 0):

Setter methods in Objective-C equate to a reatain of the new object and release of the old object.  In your case the compiler will generate a setter method for your myString property that looks something like...

```
- (void)setMyString:(NSMutableString*)aString {
    [myString autorelease];
    myString = [aString retain];
}
```

When you invoke self.myString = in your init method this translates to a call to the setter.  The setter in turn retains the object you pass to it.  Because you've directly alloc'd the NSString it begins life with a retain count of one, you then call the setter and the retain count becomes two.

There's two approaches to fixing the problem, the first would be to add a call to [myString autorelease] after you alloc it.  Or secondly switch your init method to directly assign the ivar...

```
// in your init method...
myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

It's a good idea to avoid setter usage in init methods, not because of retain counts but because the object as a whole is not yet fully initialized.

Answer (score -3):

@property (nonatomic, RETAIN)

you are retaining my friend. You have to release the object twice then because the retain count is 2

here is what you should do in the INIT method:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello World!"];
self.myString = str;
[str release]; // dont leak
```

Also I do not recommend using self.someProperty in the class itself. Doing so requires 1 extra objc_msgSend() to be done to access your variable and will slow down your application.

Comment: Thanks Antwan. mmmmm - I need to do some reading. I'm not familiar with the way you did it above.

Comment: @Antawn Oof, the advice against using accessor methods seems really questionable to me. Do you really think one additional message is going to create measurable overhead in an iOS app? To me, that's a fairly extreme example of premature optimization. On the other hand, getters and setters often have side effects, e.g. lazy initialization, KVO, etc., so avoiding using them means potentially sprinkling knowledge of their implementation all over your app. Not a good idea at all, IMO.

Comment: -1 for suggesting the `objc_msgSend` has overhead, but +1 for correctly identifying the issue.  Also: `[self setMyString:[NSMutableString string]];`

Comment: @Dave DeLong: Heh, well technically of course, there's some function call and lookup overhead, but ... in general that's so small on an iOS device as to be practically unmeasurable for an individual call. It would take *a lot* of extra calls to have a noticeable impact, so the only place I'd worry about optimizing that would be in a tight loop (and only if Instruments told me it was actually a problem).

Comment: @jlehr of course, but were only talking about a dozen or so instructions.  That's like... what... 12 nanoseconds per message? It's so insignificant it's *almost* not worth measuring. But I agree: it's only a problem if Instruments says its a problem.

Comment: @Dave DeLong: I totally agree; if a developer is worrying about the overhead of calling an accessor method, they're Doing It Wrong.  ;-)

Comment: -1 That last paragraph is horribly bad advice. Property accessors bring a lot of benefits to the table, like encapsulation of memory-management code and automatic support for KVO notifications. Giving up the benefits to avoid a trivial amount of overhead is a clear case of premature optimization.

Comment: @ShermPendley I see no reason why you should use a method that does - (NSString *)lol { return _lol; } 900 times instead of the variable itself. If you want to use notification systems you can use it if you need to, doesn't mean you need to use the method every single line of your class just because you have a KVONotifaciotn set up somewhere -- and what premature optimization if you prefer using an instance variable directly anyways? And who says you are going to release the instance variable? If you do self.someVar = nil; or somevar release]; somevar = nil; the result is the same

Comment: @ShermPendley @property is just for generating some code for you you otherwise would have to write yourself, doesn't mean you HAVE to use it -- I'd say use something that will run faster looks cleaner and gives you much more control

Comment: @DaveDelong [NSMutableString string] returns an autoreleased object, this is advised against by apple as you have a limited amount of RAM memory on an iOS device and again adds overhead you don't need

Comment: @Antwan except that you're `retaining` it via the property, so it would be sticking around anyway, regardless of whether you alloc/inited it or +string'd it. And where do you get that `autorelease` adds overhead and that it's "advised against by apple"? Prove it to me; show me empirical evidence gathered with Instruments and a link to the documentation where it says I shouldn't use `autorelease`.

Comment: @DaveDelong Adding the object to the autorelease pool and calling release later on while doing it yourself has the exact same effect

Comment: @Antwan right. so where's the overhead in it doing for you what you would've been doing yourself? one extra method call? that takes all of a microsecond on a 1GHz device?

Comment: @DaveDelong I don't know whether I executed this speed test completely correct, basically I create the NSAutoreleasePool before I take the start time as the creation od the NSAutoreleasoPool is not what I want to measure, however I do need to drain it before I time the end, here is the result using clock() -- if you wan't the source code add another comment: 2011-04-11 19:20:48.895 AutoReleaseFun[959:903] Speed of retain counting: 380190
2011-04-11 19:20:49.530 AutoReleaseFun[959:903] Speed of autorelease counting: 570555   (end-start, not divided by CLOCKS_PER_SEC ) 5 million NSStrings

Comment: @DaveDelong Though the overhead is small I don't like being lazy which will cost the user some responsiveness, I just don't think that we should add more overhead just because we have good hardware nowadays and then again writing everything in assembly would take ages

Comment: @Antwan so the difference is ~0.2 seconds for **5 million `NSString` objects**! (Assuming a 1GHz processor) This means that each `autorelease` is taking an extra 40 nanoseconds. OH THE OVERHEAD. This is a case of premature optimization. Fix the big problems, and then worry about `autorelease` **once you've measured and proven it to be a bottleneck**. Otherwise you're just wasting your time "fixing" something that isn't a problem.

Comment: @DaveDelong euh this was tested on my 2.0ghz Macbook5,1 ( teh first unibody ), but yeah the overhead is not that much, but it wouldn't be a bad idea of using release by itself, I don't mind typing the line [str release]; :x?

Comment: @Antwan no, it's not a bad idea to use `release`. What's a bad idea is to think you need to avoid `autorelease` because of its overhead. You have bigger fish to fry than shaving off a few nanoseconds here and there. :)

Comment: @Antwan - The problem is the trade-off. To avoid that overhead, you'd have to scatter memory management code all over the place, at each location in your code where a new value is assigned to the iVar. That turns into a debugging nightmare when (not if) one of those locations gets it wrong, and you're stuck trying to track it down and figure out which one. Don't take my word for it, just check the cocoa-dev list archives - the single most common problem people have with memory management stems directly from failing to write & use a setter method.

Comment: @Antwan - You're focusing on the CPU cost of calling a setter, but you're ignoring the complexity and maintenance cost you introduce by *not* calling the setter. It's not a worthwhile trade IMHO.

Comment: @ShermPendly usually I don't need to modify the instance variable that often that it becomes so difficult, actually never even experienced that. And xcode is so awesome that it finds most memory leaks that are out there -- and if it doesn't leaks makes it even easier to find them. Setting values is easier with the methods indeed, but usually I only need to access them anyways which is awesome with the instance variable only. Sometimes I also keep an iVar private when I want to make sure the class itself controls it ( like an NSMutableArray for a tableview ). so yeah :D